# Unexpected Identifier. react-native run-android

Tags: react-native

I am following this guide to create the project with native code (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html). But I am getting this error after the run command:
[image]

Comment: have you tried `npm install` before `react-native run-android`?

Comment: Are you using react-native 0.56 and running on Windows? @ShubhMishra

Comment: getting this error --

npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/rhdeck/cordova-node-xcode.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! undefined
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is a new bug in react-native 0.56 that affects Windows users. To solve it you can create a project with another react-native version:

```
react-native init --version="0.55.4" MyNewApp
```

You can see more infos in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20015).

Comment: It worked. But Now I am getting this error with red color: " Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment"

Comment: You need to start an android emulator (with Android Studio) or connect using the USB a real android device.

However this is another kind of problem so you can search for similar answers or create a new one.

If you think my answer solves the question problem check it as the right answer please.